# Partition Function of One-dimensional hard rods

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I was trying to follow the derivation presented in the last section, “Isobaric ensemble: an alternative” in the article on one-dimensional hard rods, available on http://www.sklogwiki.org/SklogWiki/index.php/1-dimensional_hard_rods.

It is therein found out that two partition functions, $Z$ and $Z’$, are so Laplace-related
$$Z’ (s) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}s e^{Ls}Z(L)$$ where L is a constant.
It is also known that $$Z’(s) =\lbrack \int _{0}^{\infty}dy f(y)e^{-sy} \rbrack^{N}$$ where $N$ is a constant and $f(y)$ is a function equal to 0 is $y$ is less than a constant $\sigma$and equal to 1 otherwise.
The position is made that  $s=p/kT$, $k$ being the Boltzmann constant, $p$ is the pressure and $T$ the temperature.
The final aim is to calculate
$$G=-kT log Z’ (p/kT)$$
It is said that the previous expression is easily evaluated to equal
$$G=-kT Nlog (p/kT)+p\sigma N$$
How the latter passage is justified, I do not get at all and it is well bugging me.

I can see that

$$ log \lbrack \int _{0}^{\infty}dy f(y)e^{-sy} \rbrack^{N}  = N log \int _{0}^{\infty}dy f(y)e^{-sy}$$ but then whay to I do, "infiltrate" the integral with the logarithm?

Any hint would be most appreciated, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because they call $f(y)$ the factor in front of $e^{-sy}$ doesn't mean the integral is that complicated. Substitute the definition of $f(y)$ and get to the bottom of what the integrand means:
$$
f(y) e^{-sy} = \left\{ \begin{array}{c} 0, \;\; y < \sigma\\ e^{-sy}, \;\; y \ge \sigma \end{array} \right.
$$ 
Now integrate and done.